# How to change Dropdown to Search Box in Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a datasource "Stock" with a one to one relationship with "Location".

When I drag a form to the canvas for the Stock datasource, it creates a dropdown for the Location. That's fine but there are a lot of Locations, so I want to change the dropdown to a Suggest Box. So, I have added the search box to the form and am trying to use the same options and value parameters that App Maker generated for the dropdown, but App Maker won't let me.

These are the values:

```
options: datasources.Locations.items
value: datasource.item.Locations
```

In both cases, the Save button in the editor dialog is disabled.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think by "Search Box", you mean the suggest text field widget. Since you want the value of the suggest text field to be a record, look in the proeprty editor for the section called "Suggest Box Query Options". In that section, select the model and field you want to use. Since you want to set the value of a relation make sure the "valueIsRecord" property is set to true. Don't bind options, just bind the value.

Comment: My apologies for the typo! You are quite right I was talking about the Suggest Box. I will try your suggestion tomorrow.Many thanks.